How do I add a numerical value to these texts in Excel toi SPSS? I am stuck
I am very stuck on this as a beginner in excel.
I asked a question in a survey where people could tick multiple boxes if they applied to them.
In my excel sheet from the survey Excel seperates their boxes by commas. So Lets say they could choose from "I like red" "I like blue" "I like yellow" and "I like grey", and they chose the first three.
Then in excel it shows in the cell: I like red, I like blue, I like yellow.
Now I want all these text answers to become numerical. So if they chose the previous boxes they would be assigned 1,2,3 (grey would be 4).
Then in SPSS I want to perform quantitive analysis on this. So if I want to see how many people chose "I like red" I can see that.
Thank you!

Split the text answers using Data > Text to Columns delimited by comma, then use VLOOKUP to count the occurrences after that.
